# How to create signed webhook requests in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, webhooks, signing

I have 2 nodejs microservices (let call them service x and service y). In service x, I will be making POST requests to service y.

Lets say service x will POST at this HTTPs endpoint in service y: /order/orderId

I think of service x as a webhooks producer, and service y to be webhooks consumer.

I want service y to be able to ensure that the message is coming from service x, and not from any malicious source. For this to work, I want to sign requests within service x before it makes POST request to service y.

What options do I have to sign these requests? How can I sign these reqeusts in service x, and how do I validate these requests in service y? Also what signing/encryption options do I have?

Concrete code examples in nodejs will be of great help.

Comment: What have you tried?  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I am looking for a solution to securely process webhooks in service y --- which are generated/triggered from service x. @MattMorgan

Comment: The github webhook docs explain the process you need, and do so rather beautifully.  https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/securing-your-webhooks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a secret key between the two services **exclusively** and use it to sign the requests.

**In the sender (service x):**

- Append a custom header for the HTTP POST request, `x-webhook-signature`, which will be a generated `sha256 HMAC` using the secret key:

```
function createHmacSignature(req) {
  return require("crypto")
    .createHmac("sha256", secretKey)
    .update(JSON.stringify(req.body))
    .digest("hex");
}
```

**In the receiver (service y):**

- Get the signature header:

```
req.headers["x-webhook-signature"]
```

- Using the secret key, create the `HMAC` again as above.
- Compare the resulted string with the `x-webhook-signature` header, if they match, the request origin would be the expected one.

```
function compareSignatures (signature, comparison_signature) {
  const source = Buffer.from(signature);
  const comparison = Buffer.from(comparison_signature);
  return require("crypto").timingSafeEqual(source, comparison);
}
```

Of course, extra validations and enhancements can be done, this is the normal flow to guarantee that only service x can send the request.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If we are sharing a secret key between 2 services, do I still need to identify service x using x-public-key? Also, can I use any GUID value for a secret key? would it be a good choice? if not, how should I generate one? @Majed

Comment: No, if only x is expected to send the request there's no need for the public key. the secret key can be any random string, it's usually formatted to start with ``sk_`` for production and ``sk_test_`` for sandbox.